# Determining Test for Data

Tags: r, anova, normal-distribution

I am doing some statistical analysis in R on a data from two wire pulling machines. The number of breaks in the wire were recorded using a completely randomized design.

I am trying to determine if the number of breaks is influenced by the choice of the machine. The breaks from machine A and B were recorded:

```
> a
 [1] 26 30 54 25 70 52 51 26 67 18 21 29 17 12 18 35 30 36 36 21 24 18 10 43 28 15 26

> b
 [1] 27 14 29 19 29 31 41 20 44 42 26 19 16 39 28 21 39 29 20 21 24 17 13 15 15 16 28
```

I plotted the two data sets on two qqnorm plots and got the following:

[image]

[image]

From both QQ Plots, you can see that the data is skewed and therefore not from a normal distribution. What would be an appropriate test to determine if the choice of machine has an affect on the number of wire breaks? Or is the data not so badly skewed that an assumption of a normally distributed data set would be okay?

I was originally planning on using either a z test or two sample t test but I thought that both tests assumed that you have data from a normal distribution. With the data that I have I was able to calculate the sample and population variance for a z test and returned a z value of 1.655. Compared to the tabulated z value of 1.96 for a significance level of 0.05, the null hypothesis that the means are equal can not be rejected.

Any suggestions would be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wilcoxon-Mann Whitney test is non-parametric alternative to t-test.

**EDIT:**

T test is quite robust to violations of **normality** for large samples. 
For two sample test, if the sample sizes are comparable (as in your case), then t test can be used. Additionally, sample size needed for the distribution of means to approximate normality depends on the degree of non-normality of the population. For approximately normal distributions, you won't need as large sample as a very non-normal distribution.

Also, you must check the assumption of **homogeneity of variance** before applying the test. (Commonly used test is Leven's test in SPSS and var.test() or leveneTest() from car package etc. in R). If this condition is not met, you should use the option of 'unequal variance' in the code of test.

**Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon Test:**

A non-parametric alternative to t test is Wilcoxson rank sum test (also known as Mann-Whitney U-test or Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon). This test is **more popular** because  If normality holds, it is 95% as efficient as the t-test. If normality does not hold it can be arbitrarily more efficient than the t-test.

[http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/TheresaScott/Biostats.DataAnalysis.TAScott.handout.pdf]

However, Wilcoxson test compare median not mean. Sometimes it doesn't matter but sometimes you don't want to compare medians.

To read more about Wilcoxson test, https://explorable.com/mann-whitney-u-test

[Or here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test)

In R, you can run Wilcoxson test by using wilcox.test() function.

Comment: This is really a bit brief for an answer by our standards, could you explain why you thought this was suitable?